# Ext.net grouping grid

Tags: extjs, grid, ext.net

I'm building an application that displays some results in a grid, using the Ext.NET controls.
The grid is created dynamically, in the C# code-behind. I would like to let the user see the results in a grouped grid, grouped on the first column in the grid.
I want to do this dynamically, from C#, by changing the existing grid.

How should I proceed, what properties should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [GroupingStore](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.GroupingStore) 
To dynamically change grouping, you need to use this store's `groupBy` and `clearGrouping` methods.

Here is good example from sencha -
[Grouping.html](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grouping.html) (js source code - [grouping.js](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grouping.js))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following Grouping example can help get you started, see

http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Miscellaneous/Grouping/

Comment: this posts helped me get the grouping going http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?3817-SOLVED-Grouping-in-code-behind